# Is there real-time DC offset compensation in Ettus N310?

Tags: usrp

I am working with an Ettus N310 that is being controlled by some 3rd party software.  I don't have much of an insight of how they set up and control the device, just tell it what center frequency to tune to and when to grab IQ.  If I receive a signal, let's say a tone, at or very near the center frequency, I end up with a large DC offset that jumps around every few 100 usec.  If I offset the signal well away from the center frequency, the DC offset is negligible.  From what I see in Ettus' documentation, DC offset compensation is something that's set once when the device starts receiving but it looks to me like here it is being done periodically while the USRP is acquiring data.  If I receive a signal near center frequency, the DC offset compensator gets messed up and creates a worse bias.  Is this a feature on the N310 that I am not aware of or is this probably something that the 3rd party controller is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a DC offset compensation in the N310. The N310 uses an Analog Devices RFIC (the AD9371), which has these calibrations built-in. Both the AD9371 and the AD9361 (used in the USRP E3xx and B2xx series) don't like narrow-band signals close to DC due to their calibration algorithms (those chips are optimized for telecoms signals).

Like you said, the RX DC offset compensation is happening at initialization. At runtime, the quadrature error correction kicks in. The manual holds a table of those: https://uhd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page_usrp_n3xx.html#n3xx_mg_calibrations). You can try turning off the QEC tracking and see if it improves your system's performance.

Comment: Although I've added the device argument "tracking_cals=OFF", which should disable all runtime tracking corrections, a periodic DC correction persists.  This is likely explained by this passage in the AD9371 User Guide (UG-992 Rev. B):  "The Rx/ORx channels also have dc correction tracking, which is active at all times. This calibration is not an ARM-based calibration."  That seems to suggest that it can not be turned off.

Comment: (My what-look-like-DC corrections are occurring at approximately 13 Hz.)